# pseudo code in python

Tags: python, list, pseudocode

I am fairly new to python

One of the exercises I have been given is to create the python pseudo code for the following problem:

```
write an algorithm that given a dictionary (list) of words, finds up to 10 anagrams of a given word.
```

I'm stuck on ideas on how to solve this.

Currently I have (it's not even proper pseudo)

```
# Go through the words in the list
# put each letter in some sort of array
# Find words with the letters from this array
```

I guess this is way too generalistic, I have searched online for specific functions I could use but have not found any.

Any help on specific functions that would help, in making slightly more specified pseudo code?

Comment: *I guess this is way too generalistic* why do you think it is?

Comment: @TimCastelijns In the marking section it is a 10 mark question, I would have thought there would be more steps

Comment: The steps look very good.  Only thing that looks suspect is the second step.  Maybe it should read - create all possible combinations from the  word's letters.  Outside of that, not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some help, without writing the code for you

```
#define a key method
        #determine the key using each set of letters, such as the letters of a word in 
        #alphabetical order
        #keyof("word") returns "dorw"
        #keyof("dad") returns "add"
        #keyof("add") returns "add"

#ingest the word set method
    #put the word set into a dictionary which maps
    #key->list of up to 10 angrams

#get angrams method
    #accept a word as a parameter
    #convert the word to its key
    #look up the key in the dictionary
    #return the up to 10 angrams

#test case: add "dad" and "add" to the word set. 
#    getting angrams for "dad" should return "dad" and "add"
#test case: add "palm" and "lamp" to the word set. 
#    getting angrams for "palm" should return "palm" and "lamp"

#consider storing 11 angrams in the list 
#a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11. 
#Then if a01 is provided, you can return a02-a11, which is 10 angrams
```

Comment: I did'nt want the code written for me, just indicators on what functions may be available for decent psuedo code

Comment: As shown above, try the methods `keyof`, `ingestWordSet` and `getAngrams'.